# Using mongoose findById() over more than one field?

Tags: mongoose

I have a model looks like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var tableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    version: { type: String, uppercase: true , required: true, trim: true },
    name: { type: String, uppercase: true , required: true, trim: true },
    descr: String
});
uctableSchema.index({ version: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true }); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Table', tableSchema);
```

This model will generate a collection like this

```
> db.tables.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56fc97d6e81ed6faf5e75b58"),
        "version" : "4",
        "name" : "address",
        "descr" : "contact address table"
}
```

That's all fine. I intentionally to leave mongoose to generate auto _id.

And I create a unique composite index to serve as primary key.

The data is actually imported from RDBMS via json file. So mongoimport will auto-generate _id for it. And that is fine.

The _id value does not have real meaning and I would like to retrieve, modify, and delete data by the composite primary key.

In my case, can I still use findById?

```
Model.findById(id, [projection], [options], [callback])
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [callback])   
Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, [options], [callback])
```

I understand that the first parameter id refers to _id that I don't want to use.

Is there a work around to make id parameter to refer to my composite key, version and name? Or I shouldn't use findById at all in my case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the xxxById methods are all designed to work with `_id` only.

For example, here's the source for `findById`:

```js
Model.findById = function findById(id, projection, options, callback) {
  if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
    id = null;
  }
  return this.findOne({_id: id}, projection, options, callback);
};
```

You'll need to use the more general `findOne`, `findOneAndUpdate`, and `findOneAndRemove` methods.